# whitespace to newline in batchfile (windows)

Tags: windows, batch-file

i want to convert every whitespace in input to a new line character and save to a file (say tmp.txt) with batch file windows .
input:

```
http://www.example1.com   wwwexample2com   wwwexample3com   wwwexample4com
```

to output in tmp.txt :

```
http://www.example1.com
wwwexample2com
wwwexample3com
wwwexample4com
```

how do I do that?

Comment: Should each whitespace character convert to newline? or should consecutive whitespace be treated as one?

Comment: Have you searched for how to modify text files using batch? There are lots of Q&A on this topic.

Comment: each whitespace character should convert to newline.  Thanks for comment . answer from  woxxom is perfectly working.

Comment: @Jayakrishnan - if wOxxOm's answer is what you're looking for, you should click the check mark next to his answer.

Comment: @Jayakrishnan - You claim [wOxxOm's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31881931/1012053) works perfectly, but all his variations convert any contiguous string of whitespace characters into a single newline, hence my question. wOxxOm's answer does ***not** convert every whitespace character into a newline.

Answer (score 2):

If the input is a file named "input file.txt" and the urls contain "=":

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

>"output file.txt" (for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("input file.txt") do (
    set line=%%a
    call :listtokens "!line: =" "!"
))
pause & exit

:listtokens
    if .%1==. (exit /b) else (echo %~1 & shift & goto listtokens)
```

If the input is a variable with alphanumeric words:

```
>"output file.txt" (for %%a in (%VARIABLE%) do echo %%a)
```

If the input is a file named "input file.txt" with alphanumeric words:

```
>"output file.txt" (for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("input file.txt") do (
    for %%b in (%%a) do echo %%b
))
```

If it's from a console utility that outputs alphanumeric words:

```
>"output file.txt" (for /f "delims=" %%a in ('run some command') do (
    for %%b in (%%a) do echo %%b
))
```

Comment: Thank you , i'm looking for the 2nd answer but the problem is when I use links like" https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bdKR4lPdW1Y   " the output file contains only " bdKR4lPdW1Y " part the remaining is missing .How do I do that?. Thanks for the answer .

Comment: Please note that batch treats `=`, `;` and `,` as token delimiters, so the 2nd, 3rd, and 4th options will convert those characters to newlines as well. I know the phrase "alphanumeric words" is intended to exclude problem characters, but I don't think the OP appreciates the significance. The first option will not convert `<tab>` into newline, and it can have problems if there are already quotes in the content.

Comment: Lucky the OP needed to convert urls so the quotes at least won't be a problem.

Answer (score 2):

The following pure batch script will put each space delimited "word" onto a separate line in the output. Empty lines will be stripped. The script is very robust. It should handle any ASCII text as long as every source line is <8kb. Note this will not convert other whitespace characters like tab into newlines.

```
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion

>"input.txt.new" (
  for /f "usebackq eol= tokens=* delims= " %%A in ("input.txt") do (
    set "ln=%%A"
    setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
    echo(!ln: =^

!%= This line and the empty line above must remain exactly as written=%
    endlocal
  )
)
findstr . "input.txt.new" >"output.txt"
del "input.txt.new"

type output.txt
```

However, I would not use the above because I think pure batch makes text manipulation overly complex.

I would use a [regular expression text processing utility called JREPL.BAT](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6044). It is pure script (hybrid JScript/batch) that runs natively on any Windows machine from XP onward. It is much simpler, faster, and more robust than any pure batch solution. The utility is extensively documented, and there are many regular expression tutorials available on the web.

The following one liner will efficiently put each whitespace delimtted "word" onto a separate line in the output.

```
jrepl "\S+" "$0" /jmatch /f "input.txt" /o "output.txt"
```

If you really want to convert every whitespace character into a newline, as you say in your comment, then you could use the following. But I don't think it is really what you want.

```
jrepl "\s" "\n" /x /f "input.txt" /o "output.txt"
```